# How to Make Text in a TextSwitcher Fade In Not All Aogether?

Tags: android, animation, textview, spannable

I'm trying to create an android program that features text fading in but not all at the same time.  For example, I want the sentence "The boy is tall" to fade in first with "the boy" and then have "is tall" fade in next to that.  I've been working on this for awhile now and can't figure out how to do it.  Also, I tried setting a spannable that contained different parts of the sentences and animating those but that didn't work.  Does anyone know how to perform this on android?